# Inlining Angular2 templates and stylesheets at compile time

Tags: angular

I like to have separate files for templates and styles but is it possible to have the compiler inline them at compile time? I would like to use relative paths if possible, but I know this isn't supported with SystemJS right now. Also, inlining the templates and styles at compile time would cut down on the number of files that have to be downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

To inline html templates, I recommend you look at: **gulp-angular-embed-templates**

I am currently using with it an angular2 project and works well.  Don't think you can apply relative paths though.  Here is a gulp snippet:

```js
var embedTemplates = require('gulp-angular-embed-templates');
gulp.task('compile:JsWithEmbededHtml', function () {
    return gulp.src('./wwwroot/app/**/*.js')
        .pipe(embedTemplates({
            minimize: {
                quotes: true,
                dom: {
                    xmlMode: true,
                    lowerCaseAttributeNames: false,
                    lowerCaseTags: false
                }
            },
            basePath: "wwwroot"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/app'));
});
```

For embedding css, there is **gulp-angular2-embed-sass** which was inspired by gulp-angular-embed-templates.  I have not tried out this latter plugin yet, but it is worth a look.

Comment: Thank you, this works to extend, but there is an issue: it removes the quotes from href and that creates an angular template error. I filed an issue here: https://github.com/laxa1986/gulp-angular-embed-templates/issues/22

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a task runner like gulp or grunt?

I use gulp and I've had good luck with this tool:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache

Grunt alternative: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates

These will concatenate all your templates into a module using the [script directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script)

Comment: Do those grunt/gulp examples carry over to Angular 2, as well as, Angular 1.x?

Comment: No, I'm just using basic tsconfig/package.json with vscode.

Comment: Good point @irth. I'm not sure these are suitable for Angular 2. I don't believe so.

Comment: try gulp-angular-embed-templates.  i use it it works with angular2.  The following looks promising but I have not tried it yet:  gulp-angular2-embed-sass